# how to check null for a data which is having different datatype in two tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am comparing two tables data and displaying the data if there is a mismatch between values by using c# application.Suppose i have two tables `table1` and `table2` and i want to compare the column name `Leaf` which is `integer` at `table1` and `varchar` at `table2` if there is a mismatch i will push data from `table2` to `table1`.I am generating `where` clause of oracle query dynamically which is like

```
if(changevalue=`Leaf`)
{
expression+=" AND NVL(table2.Leaf,'0') != NVL(table1.Leaf,0) and table2.Leaf is not null"
}
```

But most of the time i get exception while executing query like "invalid number".How to solve this issue?

**EDIT**

i did like to_number`(table2.Leaf) != table1.Leaf and table2.Leaf is not null`,but still some times i am getting exception(Invalid number) .table2.Leaf is of type NUMBER( 10 ) and table1.Leaf is of type VARCHAR2(30)

Answer (score 2):

You could do a number of things, the first would be to create a PLSQL function, called `isNum` or something, in oracle that tries to convert a varchar value to a number and trap the exception to return 'N'.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isNum( strVal IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  num NUMBER;
BEGIN
  num := to_number(strVal);
  RETURN 'Y';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN
    RETURN 'N';
END isNum;
```

Another method would be to use `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```
select case when REGEXP_LIKE (Leaf,'^[[:digit:]]+$') then Leaf else 0 end as Leaf
from Table;
```

Comment: Is this the simpler way?

Comment: The last option would be the simplest way, the first option would be the easiest to understand and most reusable way I guess.

Comment: Hmm i using c# application where my where clause is dynamically created based on checkbox selction ,that why i asked

Comment: You would probably want the first option then. With that you will have an easy to call function that could be used in your dynamically created where clause.

Comment: I don't understand. The OP wanted to compare values between two tables - I don't see any comparison here. What am I missing?

Comment: It wasn't all about comparing, it was about getting two like datatypes so that he *could* do a comparison, at least from my understanding. Which would allow him to avoid the `invalid number`  exception.

Answer (score 1):

A few things.

`... and NVL(table2.Leaf,'0') != NVL(table1.Leaf,0) and table2.Leaf is not null`

is overkill. For this condition to be true, table2.Leaf must not be null. If it is in fact not null, then you don't need to wrap it within NVL. And then you don't need to check table1.Leaf for null either, since null never evaluates equal to a non-null value. So this compound condition is equivalent to

```
... and table2.Leaf != table1.Leaf
```

(you don't even need to check table2.Leaf for null; the != never evaluates to true if at least one of the terms is null).

Second, you are trying to compare a string to a number, with no explicit casts. That is never a good idea. You code in c#, so you know that. Perhaps the easiest is to cast the number to a string. But you need to be careful with the format, since - for example - some of the standard formats append a space to the left of the number (to reserve room for a minus sign if the number was negative). Also, your number may be 2 but the stored string in table1 may be 2.00. So it is actually better to cast the string literal to a number, but you must make sure the values in table1.Leaf are legitimate numbers.

```
... and to_number(table2.Leaf) != table1.Leaf
```

may be all you need, if you are lucky and table1.Leaf doesn't contain any strings that can't be properly converted to numbers.

Comment: to_number(table1.Leaf)  or to_number(table2.Leaf) ?? table2 contains varchar

Comment: Sorry, I switched them inadvertently, let me fix that.

Comment: i did like to_number(table2.Leaf) != table1.Leaf and table2.Leaf is not null,but still some times i am getting exception(Invalid number) .table2.Leaf is of type NUMBER( 10 ) and table1.Leaf is of type VARCHAR2(30)

Comment: Now you have them reversed, right? talbe2.Leaf is VARCHAR2(30) and table1.Leaf is NUMBER(10)? Are you getting the error about invalid number when you try to insert? Is it possible that a number in the VARCHAR2(30) format may be more than 10 digits?